# Search the String inside array of Objects using underscore.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, underscore.js

I want to search the String inside an object using underscore.js

**JSON data**

```
{ data:
       [ 
         {'id': 1, 'name': 'New Samsung Galaxy 3' },
         {'id': 2, 'name': 'Samsung Grand'},  
         {'id': 3, 'name': 'Galaxy 3 dress new Arrival'}, 
         {'id': 4, 'name': 'Samsung Galaxy 3 black ' }, 
         {'id': 5, 'name': 'Samsung refrigerators'} 
        ];
 }
```

Let Suppose I have a **keyword** `Samsung Galaxy 3`. I want it return the matching string only.

**Like This Output :**

```
{ data:
       [ 
          {'id': 1, 'name': 'New Samsung Galaxy 3' },
          {'id': 4, 'name': 'Samsung Galaxy 3 black ' }, 
       ];
 }
```

Comment: FYI, this is not JSON but an array of objects. JSON is a *textual data format*. The problem has nothing to do with JSON.

Comment: @FelixKling this is the response data and we can manipulte it FYI.

Comment: @FelixKling it an array of JSON objects aka JSON array

Comment: I repeat what Felix said. There is no JSON here.

Comment: @rz3r0: No it's not. [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/). JSON is a *data format* (like XML, CSV, etc), not (part of) a programming language.

Comment: @AkhileshSingh: Your changed your code slightly. Even even now, what you have is not valid JSON bat that doesn't matter anyway. Any data you have must be manipulated with the language you are using, which converts JSON to a native data structure anyway. Again: not JSON problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**_filter**](http://underscorejs.org/#filter).

```
var data =
       [ 
         {'id': 1, 'name': 'New Samsung Galaxy 3' },
         {'id': 2, 'name': 'Samsung Grand'},  
         {'id': 3, 'name': 'Galaxy 3 dress new Arrival'}, 
         {'id': 4, 'name': 'Samsung Galaxy 3 black ' }, 
         {'id': 5, 'name': 'Samsung refrigerators'} 
        ];

    _.filter(data, function(item) { 
       return item.name.indexOf("Samsung Galaxy 3") != -1; 
    });
```

Comment: You can also do this without underscore using `.filter`

Comment: @Mahesh Sapkal this is related my question thnak you

Comment: @mrwillihog, yes you are right we can user Array.filter instead, however the question was to do it using underscore hence.

Comment: My task is completed i want to ask which is better ? I already used underscore in my project. And which is more faster.

Comment: Instead of the name field, I want to search all including id property. I mean if I start to find value 5 it may give {'id': 5 } object even if that value 5 in name field.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [_filter](http://underscorejs.org/#filter) or [_where](http://underscorejs.org/#where)

_filter:
Return all the elements that pass a truth test. Similarly as `select`.

_where:
Convenience version of a common use case of `filter`. Selecting only objects
containing specific `key:value` pairs.

http://jsfiddle.net/yqagfLqb/

```
var data =
   [ 
     {'id': 1, 'name': 'New Samsung Galaxy 3' },
     {'id': 2, 'name': 'Samsung Grand'},  
     {'id': 3, 'name': 'Galaxy 3 dress new Arrival'}, 
     {'id': 4, 'name': 'Samsung Galaxy 3 black ' }, 
     {'id': 5, 'name': 'Samsung refrigerators'} 
    ];

_.where(data, function(item) { 
   return item.name.indexOf("Samsung Galaxy 3") != -1; 
});

console.log(data);
```

Comment: thank you for your help i used filter. Can you tell me which is more faster. _filter or _where

Comment: @AkhileshSingh accordingly yo my experience they are pretty similar as _where it just a Convenience version of _filter. But the best would be if you Profile your JS using real data in order to see performance in your application.